# Why is JQuery Code not working on Server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**`JQuery`** code is written as below and it is not working on web server. What may be the problem?

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function loadData(page){ 
            document.getElementById('catebox').style.display = 'none';  
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "webcate.php",
                data: "page="+page,
                success: function(msg)
                {   
                    $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                    {
                        $("#container").html(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
         }  

         loadData(1);
    });
```

**Included File**

Following file is included.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Problem**

The code runs on `local` but does not work on server. Normal `javascript` works fine. But `jquery` does not work on web server.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Checked developer tools for an error? Console / network tabs?

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: why this question has 4 upvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You use Protocols `http://...` in your page to replace it with a url of
>   `https://...`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or possibly use `//` for more flexibility. Will use the *scheme* of the current URI.